# Jquery disable different buttons by forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my page i have many buttons and forms like that:

```
 <div class="rows">
          <div class="row">
            <button class="open">btn1</button>
            <form>form1
              <button class="close">submit</button>
                <button class="ave">close</button>
            </form>

          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <button class="open">btn2</button>
            <form>form2
              <button class="close">submit</button>

                     <button class="ave">close</button>
            </form>
          </div>


        </div>
```

What i wan't: The user presses a button , and that open the form attached to it. If user click **submit** button, form closed and  button that opened the form becomes unavailable. If user click **close** button, form just closing, without making button unavailable. My script:

```
$(function() {
      $('.rows').on('click', '.open', function() {
        $(this).parent().children('form').show();
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);

      });

      $('.rows').on('click', '.close', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('form').hide();

      });

    $('.rows').on('click', '.ave', function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('form').hide();
         $(this).parent('.open').attr('disabled',  false);
      });

    });



form {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Now click on close button making all buttons availiable after submit. I write wrong script, or page update after clicks?

Comment: `ReferenceError: e is not defined` You forgot `e` as parameter in `$('.rows').on('click', '.ave', function() {`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you are targetting the button with class `open` which is not a parent of the close button with class `ave`. You need to target the parent div with class `row` ( via `parent` or `closest` ) and then find it's child button.

```
$('.rows').on('click', '.ave', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('form').hide();
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.open').prop('disabled', false);
      });
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/25c0fvcy/4/